# How to use ISNULL in SQL between clause

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server stored procedure that someone wrote where they are using `isnull` in the where clause in conjunction with the between keyword.  They are using the following:

```
isnull(JobNumber, '') between @BeginJob and @EndJob
```

What will this comparison return if the `JobNumber` column is null? Thanks.

Comment: Did you try it? What was the result?

Comment: It will return true/false depending on `'' between @BeginJob and @EndJob`  I'm not sure an empty (but not null) value is ever between 2 other things.  But otherwise we don't know the rest of your statement nor do we know the data types of @BeginJob or @EndJob.

Comment: `ISNULL` does seem pointless here. But of you want to have `NULL` values too then drop the `ISNULL` and add `OR Jobnumber IS NULL`. You should never use `ISNULL` on a column In the `WHERE`, as it will have (significant) performance impacts.

Answer (score 0):

It will be translated as empty string, as ISNULL transforms the NULL values of param1 (column provided) into param2 value. So in your case you use the column values between x and y , but when null it will use ""

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0):

This expression prevents the use of index on JobNumber, if such index exists. Remove isnull, the result will still be the same, but faster.

Answer (score 0):

variable  @BeginJob  may be passed in any case with ''.Look like JobNumber column is null-able that's why in case of space get return all.

because no comparison in between two null values always get null.